# Cannot download file ios_setup.js for fbsdk

Tags: react-native-fbsdk

I'm trying to build a react-native ios app. And I'm trying to download the file ios_setup.js from curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/master/ios_setup.js. But I get the error 404: Not Found. I'm using the instructions verbatim from facebook developer site. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like it was removed in master. You can still get the latest copy from the [0.6.1 tag](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/0.6.1/ios_setup.js)

Answer (score 1):

Actually it was moved to the bin folder. You can find the file here in the current branch:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/master/bin/ios_setup.js

Comment: I was able to download it but running it does not seem make any expected changes. I have verified all parameters and location.